# Do I need to manually get new tokens for OAuth in a Django webapp?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am a little confused right now. I am using `googleapiclient` to call the Docs API, `google_auth_oauthlib.flow` to handle the authorization flow, and `google.oauth2.credentials` only for, from what I can tell, the `Credentials` class.

I need to authorize users for my app for non-short periods of time (days-months). I need to know if I need to manually refresh their tokens should they expire.

The example Flask implementation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#example) does not seem to manually need to refresh tokens if/when they expire. It says

> `# Save credentials back to session in case access token was refreshed.`

in the `test_api_request` view as if `credentials` is automatically updated with a new token when the API is called by the object returned by `build`. Is this the case? A lot of the docs regarding these libraries have limited/vague information about how the token refresh works.

If not, how do I know when the token has expired? Does the `Credentials` instance have an expiry field? How do I get a new token using the refresh token?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code from the three libraries involved, it seems like they manage refreshing the token for you and that's why they don't give you an [expires_in](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2) field from the access token.

It's actually the `drive.files().list().execute()`  expression that updates the access token because the refreshing is done per request (in case it's necessary), but it's the `build` method that makes it possible to do so. When it's called the following occurs:

- `build` calls `build_from_document` ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/21af37b11ea2d6a89b3df484e1b2fa1d12849510/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L176))
- `build_from_document` creates an instance of `AuthorizedHttp` ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/21af37b11ea2d6a89b3df484e1b2fa1d12849510/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L431))
- The `AuthorizedHttp` instance manages refreshing the token when it's necessary, by calling the `refresh` method on `Credentials` ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-httplib2/blob/master/google_auth_httplib2.py#L216))
- You can see that the `refresh` method works with an expiry field ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/oauth2/credentials.py#L191))
- And it parses the `expires_in` field given by the API. ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/06d7f97adaebb3b34ce6a159c23061dd2554e8ac/google/oauth2/_client.py#L63))

The three libraries involved in this process are [google-auth-library-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python), [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) and [google-auth-library-python-httplib2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-httplib2).

Pretty convoluted process. If you want to read a simpler implementation of an OAuth client, you could try reading the [Spotipy client](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/spotipy/oauth2.py#L409) implementation of the Authorization Code flow. It has nothing to do with the google libraries, but it might give you an idea of how it manages the token.

The gist of it is: You make a request to the token endpoint which gives you back an `expires_in` field along with the `access_token`, based on this field, you need to calculate the time in the future when this token will expire. When you make a request to the resource server, you need to check if the token is expired, if it is, you make a new request sending the `refresh_token` to the token endpoint.

I've omitted some steps, but if you want to know more, you can read about it [here](https://www.oauth.com/) and in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this explanation. So If i save the credentials back into the database after using the API, I should be good, right?

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration), the refresh_token only expires after 6 months of inactivity,  which fits your use case. So yes, you're good.

Comment: Actually you might need to parse the response for errors when refreshing the token and redirect the user to the `\authorize` endpoint. I believe it'll throw an HttpError, but I can tell you for sure sorry.

Comment: One way to find out what happens would be to authenticate with your google account, revoke your app access in the [permissions page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and then try to get a new `access_token` using the (now expired) `refresh_token` to see what error it gives.